# Updating MetaData in MP3 file created using bytearray in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, dart-packages

I am currently recording a live stream and writing it to a file in flutter using bytearray and reading it as a stream and then writing it to a file using `File.openWrite` and all is going well however I just realized I need to write some metadata to the file and I have no idea how to even go about that. I have done this once in Android using the ID3Tag library but I cannot seem to find anything similar to that in Flutter. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance as usual! I have tried using https://pub.dev/packages/audiotagger/

However, I keep running into this error and have no idea how to fix this. `Checking further because the ID3 Tag ends at 0x00 but the mp3 audio doesn't start until 0x129`

This is also part of the error:

```
W/System.err(20398): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.jaudiotagger.tag.Tag.setField(org.jaudiotagger.tag.FieldKey, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
W/System.err(20398):    at com.nicolorebaioli.audiotagger.AudiotaggerPlugin$Util.setFieldIfExist(AudiotaggerPlugin.java:222)
W/System.err(20398):    at com.nicolorebaioli.audiotagger.AudiotaggerPlugin.writeTags(AudiotaggerPlugin.java:92)
W/System.err(20398):    at com.nicolorebaioli.audiotagger.AudiotaggerPlugin.onMethodCall(AudiotaggerPlugin.java:64)
W/System.err(20398):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
W/System.err(20398):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
W/System.err(20398):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
W/System.err(20398):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(20398):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
W/System.err(20398):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to do this by using the flutter ffmpeg library.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg/

Once you add this to your file use the code below to add the metadata to the file.

```
void ffmpegFileUpdate(fileName) {
  var abs = absolutePath + "/temp.mp3";
  var newP = absolutePath + "/" + fileName;

  final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
  var arguments = ["-i", abs, "-c:v", "mp3", newP];
  _flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(arguments).then((rc) {
    File(abs).delete();    
  });
}
```